# Perl debugger error @ C:/Perl/lib/Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm line 65

Tags: perl, debugging, require

I'm having a strange error trying to run a Perl script with ActivePerl on Windows XP:

```
>perl -d quick_translate_missing.pl < translate_en.txt > new.txt

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `perldoc perldebug' for more help.

main::(quick_translate_missing.pl:9):
9:      my $not_translated = '\'EN_([\w\s]+)\'';
El sistema no puede hallar la ruta especificada.
Unknown error
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl/lib/Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm line 65.
 at C:/Perl/lib/Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm line 65
        Term::ReadLine::Perl::new('Term::ReadLine', 'perldb', 'GLOB(0x1968f34)',
 'GLOB(0x1927e7c)') called at C:/Perl/lib/perl5db.pl line 6068
        DB::setterm called at C:/Perl/lib/perl5db.pl line 2241
        DB::DB called at quick_translate_missing.pl line 9
Attempt to reload Term/ReadLine/readline.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl/lib/Term/ReadLine/Perl.pm line 65.
END failed--call queue aborted at quick_translate_missing.pl line 65.
 at quick_translate_missing.pl line 65
```

"El sistema no puede hallar la ruta especificada." means "System cannot find the specified path". The line the error is referring to is from Perl.pm:

```
eval {require Term::ReadLine::readline}; die $@ if $@;
```

What I understand is that it cannot find Term::ReadLine::readline, but the file C:\Perl\lib\Term\ReadLine\readline.pm is there. Also PATH is set correctly since I can run perl interpreter from anywhere without specifing the path.

The error happens only when using standard **output** redirection (>). Script passed to debugger doesn't matter, it crashes on all if output redirection used.

Any clues? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This may not help you if you **must** have a specific perl version, but I found this same error with my perl 5.8.5 install.  I could **not** upgrade on one machine (for legacy code reasons), but I ran it in another perl environment with the latest perl (v5.14.2) and this "debugger" bug has been solved (although I suspect you may have the same result by updating the Term::ReadLine::* modules as well).  By the way, this isn't specific to ActivePerl -- I saw this on Linux as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although this is not an issue anymore :)